# Add class or style if text in div appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styles

i have this order form which i'm making.
Right now when someone put a coupon code I want to apply to the div of the old price a style or class (line-through) and i though I had it right...here is what i'm doing.....any suggestion why it might not be working? WARNING: I am really new to javascript....i've been working with CSS HTML but javascript is another story. Thanks!

```
if ($('#grand_amount_value').length > 1){
    $("#Total_Amount_old_val").attr("style", "text-decoration:line-through");
}
```

Comment: `if ($('#grand_amount_value').length > 1)` . Are you sure you want to check for this length to be greater than 1? Because normally, you should be checking if that element exists, which implies the length is 1, not greater than 1.

Comment: Try `if ($('#grand_amount_value').length){
    $("#Total_Amount_old_val").attr("style", "text-decoration:line-through");
}`

Comment: Thanks.
Still doesn't work...I really don't know what can be wrong to be honest. :/

Comment: You need to provide us more details about your scenario. One thing is clear that the current code will only fire if you have an element with id `grand_amount_value` present on the page. If this element is added dynamically upon some event, you need to fire this code also after the element has been inserted into the page.

Comment: Yeah I think something around there im missing...the element is there but the text that appears after I click on the button appears after this action...

`document.getElementById("btn_applypromo").onclick = function() {myFunction()
if ($('#grand_amount_value').length){ $("#Total_Amount_old_val").attr("style", "text-decoration:line-through"); }
};`

Im guessing here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I threw together to show something like that working:

https://jsfiddle.net/pj6xwhcy/3/

```js
function strikeOldAmt() {
    var gav = $("#grand_amount_value");
    if (gav.length > 0 && gav.text() != "" ){
        // There is a GAV element and it is not empty, strike out the old amount!
        $("#Total_Amount_old_val").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    }
}
```

Note: Using the "style" attribute would also wipe out any other custom styling you may have added. Using the `css()` function will not interfere if the style attribute is already set.

Comment: This is exactly what i want! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the page isn't reloading you could use a setInterval to check if the element exists.

```
var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){
if ($('#grand_amount_value').length){
    $("#Total_Amount_old_val").attr("style", "text-decoration:line-through");
    clearInterval(checkInterval);
}
},200);
```

Comment: This applies the style...but even if there is no value on grand_amount_value though...weird.

Comment: replace the "if" statement with `if ($('#grand_amount_value').val().length != 0){` and that will check for 1) that #grand_total_value exists and 2)that it's value is not equal to null

Answer (score 0):

Simplest clean way

```
$(document).on('change','#grand_amount_value',function(){ 
    if ($('#grand_amount_value').val().length != 0){
    $('#Total_Amount_old_val').css('text-decoration','line-through');
    }
});
```

or if you need continuous check

```
$(document).on('keypress','#grand_amount_value',function(){ 
        if ($('#grand_amount_value').val().length != 0){
        $('#Total_Amount_old_val').css('text-decoration','line-through');
        }
    });
```

[Here a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/goese56s/1/)